# Nginx + hhvm + mysql: Timeout or waiting for long time for first request

Tags: nginx, hhvm

A very weird problem:

My site is a typical Linux + hhvm + nginx + mysql site, and when I open my site, here is what happen:

1. Type address, hit enter.
2. Waiting for response for a long time, sometimes I even get a timeout.
3. IF I hit the refresh immediately after hitting enter in the first stage, the site loads smoothly.

Where could the problem be?

Here is my nginx configure:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    #listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;
include /var/www/xxx/nginx.conf;
    root /var/www/xxx;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name xxx.xxx
    location / {
            # try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

#fastcgi_cache start
set $no_cache 0;

# POST requests and urls with a query string should always go to PHP
if ($request_method = POST) {
    set $no_cache 1;
}   
if ($query_string != "") {
    set $no_cache 1;
}   

# Don't cache uris containing the following segments
if ($request_uri ~* "(/wp-admin/|/xmlrpc.php|/wp-(app|cron|login|register|mail).php|wp-.*.php|/feed/|index.php|wp-comments-popup.php|wp-links-opml.php|wp-locations.php|sitemap(_index)?.xml|[a-z0-9_-]+-sitemap([0-9]+)?.xml)") {
        set $no_cache 1;
}   

# Don't use the cache for logged in users or recent commenters
if ($http_cookie ~* "comment_author|wordpress_[a-f0-9]+|wp-postpass|wordpress_no_cache|wordpress_logged_in") {
    set $no_cache 1;
} 



location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
    access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
}

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
            root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    }
location ~ \.php$ {
try_files $uri =404;
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
fastcgi_cache_bypass $no_cache;
fastcgi_no_cache $no_cache;
fastcgi_cache  microcache;
fastcgi_cache_key $scheme$host$request_uri$request_method;
fastcgi_cache_valid 200 301 302 30s;
fastcgi_cache_use_stale updating error timeout invalid_header http_500;
fastcgi_pass_header Set-Cookie;
fastcgi_pass_header Cookie;
fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
#fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_index index.php;
include fastcgi_params;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Added the following to my HHVM server.ini. You will need to change it to point at your MySQL socket if your server is local or remote.
you can look the Location of your server socket with

> cat /etc/mysql/my.cnf

in Mariadb jessie example is /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

Add example in your server.ini:

> hhvm.mysql.socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock